# В яндекс картах у маркера пропадает _element после приближения карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При использовании кластеров, если сначала отдалить карту, затем кликнуть на кластер, то при клике на точку, у маркера пропадает _element. Как это починить?
[image: скриншот девтулса]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да, если вопрос актуален, покажите минимальный рабочий пример, где ситуация воспроизводится. И хорошо бы уточнить, зачем использовать параметр, который не является у Яндекса обязательным (все, начинающиеся с подчёркивания)?